# Convergence of Shanks Transformation

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

If sequence $A_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, and the Shanks Transformation of $A_n$ defined as $$S\left(A_n\right)=\frac{A_{n+1}A_{n-1}-A_n^2}{A_{n+1}+A_{n-1}-2A_n}$$ also converges, prove $S\left(A_n\right)$ converges to zero.

It's problem 8-1 in Carl M. Bender's book, *Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers*. I tried the definition of limit but couldn't finish the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Equivalently $S(A_n)=A_{n-1}-\frac{(\Delta A_{n-1})^2}{\Delta^2 A_{n-1}}$ with the *forward difference operator* $\Delta u_n:=u_{n+1}-u_n$. (Note the problem statement should have included $\Delta^2 A_n\ne 0$.) Thus $$\frac{S(A_n)}{A_{n-1}}=1-\frac{\Delta A_{n-1}}{A_{n-1}}\cdot\frac{\Delta A_{n-1}}{\Delta^2A_{n-1}}.$$By Stolz–Cesàro this has limit $1-1=0$, so $S_n$ has limit $0\times 0=0$.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't heart about Stolz–Cesàro theorem before but wiki says that it can be viewed as a l'Hôpital's rule for sequences, which makes this easier to grasp. However, the statement of Stolz–Cesàro theorem says that the sequence in the denominator is strickly monotonic and divergence, while in our case, the sequence $A_{n-1}$ is neither monotonic nor divergence. So why can we apply this theorem?

Comment: @Bruce You can get divergence by working with sequences such as $1/A_n$.

Comment: @J.G. Hey, I am wondering what is $\delta ^2 A_{n-1}$ ? Is that the second directive ?

Comment: @MathAvengers The second forward difference, i.e. $\Delta^2 u_n:=u_{n+2}-2u_{n+1}+u_n$.